# How can i grab a string, having no unique chars to grab from in between?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to grab a the image name from the URL itself, which is kind of dynamic.

The URL looks like:

https://test.xx-1.xx.xx.xx/xx/fb88442930ff540ceb5291d26354ee8a/5DA5E231/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/65542766_147243723033642_3920490496418948592_n.jpg?_nc_ht=xx.xx-1.xx.xx.com

My goal is to grab only this "**65542766_147243723033642_3920490496418948592**" from the URL.

I have tried grabbing "**65542766_147243723033642_3920490496418948592**" string from the URL keeping "**s640x640**" & "**_n**" as uniquely identified and grabbing the string in between that works but somewhere in a point "**s640x640**" this thing becomes dynamic according to the image height and length so my python program breaks.

```
def verify_duplicate_pictures(s):
    result = re.search(r"(?<=640/).*?(?=_n)", s).group(0)
    return result
s = 'https://test.xx-1.xx.xx.com/xx/fb88442930ff540ceb5291d26354ee8a/5DA5E231/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/65542766_147243723033642_3920490496418948592_n.jpg?_nc_ht=xx.xx-1.xx.xx.com'

verify_duplicate_pictures(s)
```

The result from my code which i get is

result:

```
'65542766_147243723033642_3920490496418948592'
```

but whenever the URL gets dynamic and "**s640x640**" changes to something else my program breaks.

Comment: Does the filename always come after the last `/` and always come with a file extension?

Comment: @Chillie yes the filename always comes after the last `/` and always with the file extension.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef you can regex last part of url from last '/' to the '.'

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I tried but i'm not that strong with regex.

Comment: [Try without regex](https://ideone.com/tJllgV)

Comment: Lastly, is `_n` the permanent postfix on all images you're trying to get or does it change as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You go:

```
import re

url = 'https://test.xx-1.xx.xx.xx/xx/fb88442930ff540ceb5291d26354ee8a/5DA5E231/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/65542766_147243723033642_3920490496418948592_n.jpg?_nc_ht=xx.xx-1.xx.xx.com'
out = re.findall("\w+_n", url)[0][:-2]
```

Output:

```
65542766_147243723033642_3920490496418948592
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works for me. Not able to cast a up vote because i have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: Can you help me to understand the regex you wrote?

Comment: @0xdeadbeef you can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cRYCs7/1) to practice with regular expressions.

Comment: @0xdeadbeef best read this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html then you will understand